# Syntax highlighting for PHP ini file

Tags: support

After looking at [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109) and trying a few random workarounds I'm still looking for a syntax choice that will correctly parse a PHP ini file.

At the minimum it would be great if it could recognize a semi-colon `;` as the beginning of a comment. Is there an appropriate choice or replacement?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think your best bet is to go with Lisp. That's a programming language which uses semicolons to indicate comments at the start of a line.

The square brackets don't do anything in lisp syntax highlighting.

Add `<!-- language: lang-lsp -->` in front of your code block.

Sample:

```lsp
[PHP]
; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://php.net/precision
precision = 14
; PHP's default character set is set to UTF-8.
; http://php.net/default-charset
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: looks like that would be an acceptable workaround.  I tried a handful and googled "languages that use semi-colon for comments" but came up with nothing.  thanks!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Inline_comments) is always a good resource :)

Comment: the wikipedia link was the first result in my google search but I failed to notice that nice table of inline comment comparisons.